# Why does typing in my site's IP address bring up a different site?

Tags: domains, dns, networking

I do not understand how domains are connected to IP addresses. I have a certain domain e.g. example.com. I run `ping example.com` and get its IP address from DNS query.

When I type this IP in address line in browser, it brings me to another site. Please explain to me the reason that might happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTTP protocol that is used to load websites by your browser supports a "Host" header which tells the server which hostname was typed into the url bar of the browser. This way, the same server (same IP) can handle different websites.

Imagine `www1.example.com` and `www2.example.com both` resolve to `127.0.0.42`.

The Server on `127.0.0.42` on port 80 listens to HTTP requests. If you open `http://www1.example.com` in your browser, the browser connects to `127.0.0.42:80` and sends the `Host: www1.example.com` header along with the request. This way the server can serve the site for `www1.example.com`.

If you enter `http://www2.example.com`, your browser also connects to `127.0.0.42:80`, but this time sets the `Host: www2.example.com` header, thus the sever knows that this time it has to serve the other page.

If you open `http://127.0.0.42` in your browser, the server will get the `Host: 127.0.0.42` header along with the request. This time the server may not know which site to serve, so it may present an error, or fall back to a default website. This is why you may see a different site if you browse to the IP instead of the hostname.

Comment: The Apache webserver is the most common webserver out there.   It serves up the first configured site as the default when the `Host:` header doesn't match any of the configured sites.